# Junit not catching FileNotFoundException

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit5

I runt into something strange. I have a method to read from a CSV file, line by line. The method takes the filePath and in my JUnit test, I'm testing this method with the wrong filePath expecting to get a FileNotFoundException. The thing is that JUnit5 doesn't throw that exception but in the eclipse console I can see that the JVM throws that exception, so I'm struggling to understand why

I've set up my test code to throw the exception but it doesn't get thrown. I tried to catch Exception but still no joy.

Here is the method and the test method

```
public void readData(String COMMA_DELIMITER, String READ_FILE_PATH) {
    BufferedReader br = null;
    try {
        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(READ_FILE_PATH));
        String line = "";
        //Read to skip the header
        br.readLine();
        //Reading from the second line
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) 
        {

            String[] employeeDetails = line.split(COMMA_DELIMITER);
            populateModel(employeeDetails);
        }

        //Lets print the Employee List
        for(Employee e : empList)
        {
            System.out.println(e.getName() + "; " + e.getSurname() + "; " + e.getDateOfBirth() + "; " + e.getSex());
        }


    } 
    catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

@Test
    void testWrongFilePath() {
        String READ_FILE_PATH_WRONG = System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/teest/XXXFile.csv";
        System.out.println(READ_FILE_PATH_WRONG);
        Assertions.assertThrows(FileNotFoundException.class, () -> {
            readData.readData(COMMA_DELIMITER, READ_FILE_PATH_WRONG);
        });     
    }
```

In the console, I get the FIleNotFOundException, but the output of the test says that

```
org.opentest4j.AssertionFailedError: Expected java.io.FileNotFoundException to be thrown, but nothing was thrown.
```

Comment: You have caught the `FileNotFoundException`, which means it will not be thrown by the method. Try not catching it and maybe annotate the method with `throws FileNotFoundException`.

Comment: OK thanks, I added `throws FileNotFoundException` as suggested but I then had to of course wrap the caller - inside the main method - in the try and catch statements. Now, this way we get the test working, which is great, but my gut feeling - which of course could be wrong - seems to suggest that catching the exceptions in the readData method is better than catching them in the caller. What do you think?

Comment: It is of course better, but then your method will not throw a `FileNotFoundException` which means you have to return something meaningful in that case. The suggestion about the `boolean` return value isn't bad, I think you can go that way. Make the method return a `boolean` and `return false;` in the `catch` block where you catch the exception. It's a common practive to return a `boolean` to indicate the action performed has been successful or not.

Comment: Catching the exception is *not* better!  When other code calls your method, they expect it will have successfully read the data.  If the method couldn’t successfully complete its task, it needs to *let the caller know that,* and the best way to do that is by either letting the FileNotFoundException propagate, or wrapping it in an application-specific exception.

Comment: @deHaar Returning a `boolean` definitely is not a good practice.  How is a caller supposed to know what went wrong?  This, in fact, is why the old `File.delete` method (and all methods of java.io.File) was replaced with [Files.delete](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/Files.html#delete%28java.nio.file.Path%29), which properly throws an exception instead of making the caller guess why false was returned.

Comment: @VGR I wrote it is a *common practice*, but you are right with the rest of what you wrote. What about a `RuntimeException` at catching?

Comment: @deHaar Making the caught exception the cause of a new RuntimeException is definitely better than suppressing or just printing/logging the exception.  Whether it’s the best approach is highly dependent on the nature of the method and the nature of the caught exception.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot expect from your Assertion framework to catch an exception that is caught inside your SUT:

```
catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

You either have to :

- Log then rethrow same / different exception and assert on that.
- Make your method return Boolean as a success equivalent which you can then assert on.

Answer (score 1):

You're catching the `FileNotFoundException` within `readData`.

Try refactoring so that you don't have a try-catch, and have `public void readData(String COMMA_DELIMITER, String READ_FILE_PATH) throws IOException { ...`

(`FileNotFoundException` is a subclass of `IOException`.)

Answer (score 0):

```
assertThrows(Class<T> expectedType, Executable executable)
```

doesn't assert that an exception is thrown at a time in your code (which is the true in your case). But that asserts that the statement invoked in the `Executable` lambda throws an exception (which is false in your case).

Since you caught the `FileNotFoundException` in the method under test, the exception is never propagates to the lambda return and JUnit can only emit an error because the expected exception was not encountered.

To assert such a thing, don't catch the exception by removing the `catch` statement and instead of declare `throws` `FileNotFoundException` in the declaration of the tested method :

```
public void readData(String COMMA_DELIMITER, String READ_FILE_PATH) throw FileNotFoundException {...}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your method doesn't throw `FileNotFoundException`: you catch it, print the stack trace, and carry on as if no exception occurred:

```
catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

JUnit isn't magic: it can't detect things that happen inside the method, other than by detecting side effects (values returned, uncaught exceptions, mutating state).